# How to pass data from the BrowserWindow to the main process in Electron?

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron, eventemitter

I would like to save the window position and size of my electron `BrowserWindow`. Due to various reasons, I would like to pass the data back to `main.ts` first (it is holding the custom node module) and let it decide what to do with it.

It was already explained to me that `BrowserWindow` is part of the main process and thus I don't need to use `IPC` and a simple `EventEmitter` should suffice. However, I can't get it to work. Here is my `main.ts` creating the `EventEmitter` in a simplified example:

```
import EventEmitter from 'events';
const ee = new EventEmitter();
ee.on('event', () => {
  console.log("got an event...!");
});
```

And here the `CustomWindow.ts`:

```
import { BrowserWindow } from "electron";
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';

export default class CustomWindow extends BrowserWindow {
  typeKey: string;
  eventEmitter: EventEmitter;

  constructor(typeKey: string, preloadPath: string) {
    super({
      show: false,
      webPreferences: {
        sandbox: true,
        preload: preloadPath,
        nodeIntegration: true,
      }
    });
    this.typeKey = typeKey;
    this.eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

    this.on("ready-to-show", () => {
      this.eventEmitter.emit('event');
    });
  }
}
```

I'm pretty inexperience regarding Javascript/TypeScript, so any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just to clarify how you're instantiating your windows, please [edit] this question and include a [mcve] so your problem is easily reproducible. On another note, what prevents you from subscribing to the `BrowserWindow`'s events using `.on()` directly when instantiating the window? Also, you will need to emit and listen for events on the same `EventEmitter`, so you'd once again would have to use `customWindow.eventEmitter.on()` which is not superior to `customWindow.on()` (assuming `var customWindow = new CustomWindow(...)`) in the first place.

Comment: @Markstar When you say **save**, you mean save to file? And what decision does your main process need to make regarding the position and size of your window?